# Flutter: Show only part of Widget

Tags: html, flutter

I am using the flutter_html but I do only want to display part of the widget. Since the input are always unknown, I want to display only 3 lines or a specific height of the widget. How should I do it? The hidden part of the widget should not occupy the entire space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap `Html` inside `SizedBox` with specific height

```
SizedBox(
  child: Html(
    data: ....
  ),
 ),
```